# failing to load resource 404 github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I have already check some topic like this one to find some help, but, honnestly i still don't know how to fix it.

So, i did a little project and i'm trying to put it on github pages.

link of project : https://zkittygb.github.io/cv/

Now, when i m going to check my pages, i got some errors 404 (6 to be exact).

i already did a build, install gh-pages lib and add :   "homepage": "https://github.com/zKittyGB/cv.git" in my package.json.

Then i did a build and a deploy.

I fixed 3 of them after deleting link in the manifest, but i still have the error about main.js and main.css.

So, how can i fixe it?

Is it a link issue again?

If yes, where should i change them ? directly in the build folder ?

Thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use react for make static website and want hosting im suggest use gatsby cloud free, netlify , and vercel , i dont know if github can read js 6

Comment: So i tried with netlify and i get exactly the same issue : 
https://splendorous-sawine-daba01.netlify.app

Comment: try local okay ? not problem ?

Comment: Yeah, in local everything goes right. but,  i tried to change that : "    <script defer="defer" src="/zkittygb/cv/static/js/main.10c7f512.js"></script> "in the build code by " <script defer="defer" src="static/js/main.10c7f512.js"></script> ". Then it works on netlify (except for the assets, but i'm on the good way i guess.   (but still not work on github, maybe cause of js6 like you told me)

Comment: yeah im just know github can hosting jekyll and hugo, but posible use react if you call babel stand alone <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script> 

but your load webiste slow